# Facebook permissions limited use

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-permissions

I'm building a device that displays notifications to the user through an LCD. It connects to your computer through Bluetooth and connects to the web through a Java application which sends a request to a php script held on my server. This PHP script then uses a Facebook access token to read the users mail box and notifications to find unread counts and sends it to the device.

I was looking at Facebook's documentation on read_mailbox and manage_notifications permissions and found they had 'limited use'. They said,

> This permission is granted to apps building a Facebook-branded client
>   on platforms where Facebook is not already available. For example,
>   Android and iOS apps will not be approved for this permission. In
>   addition, Web, Desktop and TV apps will not be granted this
>   permission.

See [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2) for full documentation.

They say these permissions are only granted to Facebook-branded clients where Facebook is not already available however what exactly does this mean?

Comment: What they say is that those permissions are exclusive for them (is there any platform not listed there?). Anyway, did you get lucky with the review? Did they finally granted you those permissions? I'm in the same situation, I need both "read_mailbox" and "manage_notifications" for an Android app. Just submitted for review, fingers crossed...

Comment: I did indeed get those permissions. I think its because I had a unique hardware platform. I've recenrtly launched my new Kickstarter which is an updated version of my last where I got those permissions. https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/jackt/noteu-facebook-twitter-email-at-a-glance

Comment: Wow, your project looks amazing. Good luck with the crowdfunding and keep up the good work! As I expected, my app got revoked... so I will have to unpublish it :(

Comment: Thank you! and I'll defiantly try!! I got rejected at first too, I had to specifically explain that my platform was unique with uploading videos of it working. If you think you meet the guidelines just try and try again explaining your case.